# The migration of a list field doesn't work

Tags: migrations

In Drupal 10 I have a field of type List (text) configured with key|label that I need to populate with a migration.

My yml file seems not to work, in the 'process' block I tried with:

```
  process:
    field_select: key
```

```
  process:
    field_select/key: key
```

```
 process:
    field_select:
      plugin: get
      source: key
```

Note that the source field names here (key) were defined by the 'fields' configuration for the source plugin above.

I'm looking for full documentation or some examples with the various field types.

Comment: The first and the third are correct, they do both exactly the same. The 2nd one would fill the `key` sub-column of the `field_select` field, which does not exist for this field type.

Comment: Thanks @hudri, maybe it's my _json api_ that has something wrong... Is there a documentation somewhere about the various types of fields?